# cannot access to /q/dev on quarkus from an uber-jar despite being in dev

Tags: quarkus

I recently start deploying my quarkus project utilising a jar build by uber-jar
now each time I try to acces to /q/dev or anything like that, I have this error :

RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://participeo-monchoixdevie-api-dev.emotic.fr/q/dev/

Any idea?

I'm running in profil dev.

Comment: Running in dev-mode and running from an uber-jar are mutually exclusive. If you're running an uber-jar, you are not in dev mode, and so the dev mode facilities are unavailable. Perhaps you mean that you compiled the uber-jar with `quarkus.profile=dev`, but that is a bad idea to do (it will probably only affect the set of used configuration values, but won't activate dev mode). Dev mode is what you get by executing `mvn quarkus:dev` on the project.

Comment: @JanMartiška best add that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Running in dev-mode and running from an uber-jar are mutually exclusive. If you're running an uber-jar, you are not in dev mode, and so the dev mode facilities are unavailable. Perhaps you mean that you compiled the uber-jar with `quarkus.profile=dev`, but that is a bad idea to do (it will probably only affect the set of used configuration values, but won't activate dev mode). Dev mode is what you get by executing `mvn quarkus:dev` on the project (or an equivalent if you're using Gradle).